# Error while adding to List

Tags: asp.net

I am facing issue while adding object to List. I am using .NET framework 2.0.

Code for creating and addling objectto list.

```
List<GetInvalidElement> objInvaliElement = new List<GetInvalidElement>();
objInvaliElement.Add(new GetInvalidElement() {ElementType="Accomodation",ElementId=intACC,ElementInvalidReason=strErrorMessage});
```

Code for GetInvalidElement :

```
public class GetInvalidElement
    {
        private string _elementType;
        private int _elementId;
        private string _elementInvalidReason;

        public string ElementType
        {
            get { return _elementType; }
            set { _elementType = value; }
        }
        public int ElementId
        {
            get { return _elementId; }
            set { _elementId = value; }
        }
        public string ElementInvalidReason
        {
            get { return _elementInvalidReason; }
            set { _elementInvalidReason = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use anonymous constructors in 2.0, it was introduced in 3.0. You will have to create instance and assign the values to the properties via the instance.